# Is there a semantic difference between 'supply-demand gap' and 'demand-supply gap'?

Tags: word-usage, compounds

I have confirmed that both 'supply-demand gap' and 'demand-supply gap' have been used, although the latter is by far more common.

I wonder if X-Y gap suggests that X was higher than Y, or vice-versa?

Many Thanks

Comment: Regardless of which way round you specify it, (supply-demand or demand-supply), it's still the same ***gap*** - a ***shortfall***, because there's not enough supply to meet demand. If there was an ***oversupply / glut***, that wouldn't be referred to as a "gap".

Comment: This is about jargon and is better asked on the Economics SE group.

Comment: Per [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=supply-demand+gap%2Csupply+demand+gap%2Cdemand-supply+gap%2Cdemand+supply+gap&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csupply%20-%20demand%20gap%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csupply%20demand%20gap%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdemand%20-%20supply%20gap%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdemand%20supply%20gap%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csupply%20-%20demand%20gap%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csupply%20demand%20gap%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdemand%20-%20supply%20gap%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdemand%20supply%20gap%3B%2Cc0), both sequences are in common use.

Comment: The only real difference is the emphasis on one word or the other (whichever one comes first).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on the Economics site.

Comment: @FumbleFingers fails to realise that a gap can be due to a relatively higher supply or relatively higher demand. In **either** case. With corresponding shortfall in demand and supply, _respectively_.

Comment: @Greybeard assumes (wrongly, in my honest opinion) that the rule isn't productive in English. c.f. X-turned-Y (sportsman-turned-author)

Comment: @Bassford: Lemme restate my question. An apple demand-supply gap is ambiguous between too many apples or too many apple-eaters. Will an apple 'supply-demand' gap elicit similar intuitions? If not, then this isn't a matter of articulatory stress. See my comment to Greybeard above

Comment: @FumbleFingers Just to correct my last comment: _"In either case, there will be a corresponding shortfall"_

Comment: Well, we can always *contrive* a "shortage of buyers". I imagine if I couldn't do the coding myself, I could just pay someone else to write the code to generate a billion of my new FFS-crypto token. Then I could complain about the supply-demand gap (I have a vast supply of something that ***no-one*** wants to buy! :)

Comment: @harry On the contrary I am more concerned that, to an economist, the two forms may have separate meanings. Indeed, they may be specialised terms.